# Identify this screen connector

Tags: display, adapter, laptop-display, display-adapter

I have taken apart my old (Compaq) laptop, and I'd like to see if there is a way to reuse the screen. The connector is shown below, but it has no labels so I am wondering whether this is a generic connector or not. (and whether I'd be able to use an adapter to connect it via VGA/HDMI/DVI)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "guessing game" questions are not useful to others. See http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7647/are-hardware-port-cable-etc-visual-identification-questions-allowed-or-not and http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6073/are-guessing-game-type-questions-allowed-on-su

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is almost guaranteed to be proprietary.**  Laptop cables have to carry more than the video signals, and so they do not use shared port/wiring setups (except between similar models from that manufacturer).

Other uses of that cable include things like power for the screen and backlight, and possibly other data such as wirless signals (WiFi or WLAN) since their antennas a frequently embedded on the screen side of the laptop for better reception.  You may be able to find a pin-out diagram for this cable and determine if an adapter can be built, but as it is now, you are not going to be able to use it in anything but a similar style laptop.